# How to identify design system or design language used by app or website

Tags: website-design, interaction-design, design-patterns, user-centered-design, ux-designer

Have few doubts.

1. I'm new to UX, how to identify which design system is used by app / website, can we judge by looking into its UI.
2. Can i design my own design system for my app and website - for this design system should i follow which guidelines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to create your own design system

https://www.designbetter.co/design-systems-handbook

It is not necessary for an application or a website to follow defined systems. However, it is preferred to have one so that a consistent experience is delivered. Also, it saves time not redesigning the wheel.

It is possible to sometimes figure out if a site is using a pre-defined system but not all the details. For example, a Wordpress site will display references to Wordpress API in the code.